# Ellipsis in CakePHP bootstrap pagination shows outside the box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

The CakePHP3 pagination helper is not properly rendering with the list.
I need to show the pager like :

> ```
> |First|1|2|...|12|13|Last|
> ```

On the third page:

> ```
> |First|1|2|3|...|12|13|Last|
> ```

On the seventh page:

> ```
> |First|1|2|...|6|7|8|...|12|13|Last|
> ```

By default, I got the proper bootstrap pagination like:

> ```
> |First|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|Last|
> ```

from this code:

```
<?php
echo $this->Paginator->first(__('First'), array('tag' => 'li'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','currentTag' => 'a', 'currentClass' => 'active','tag' => 'li','first' => 1));
echo $this->Paginator->last(__('Lastssss'), array('tag' => 'li','currentClass' => 'disabled'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
?>
```

After a little research, I got some extra options like setting `'modulus'` and changing `'first'` and `'last'` like `'first' => 2` and `'last' => 2`, and the code looks like:

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('modulus' => 8, 'first' => 2,'last' => 2, 'separator' => '','currentTag' => 'a', 'currentClass' => 'active','tag' => 'li'));
```

But this shows the ellipsis(...) outside like:

> ```
> |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|12|13|Last|...
> ```

and the paginator is not showing the page numbers properly.

I need to get a pagination like the one I showed above or a pagination something like the **Google Search** pagination.

Please help. I am not that experienced with CakePHP. Thank you.

Comment: Checkout the [Bootstrap UI](https://github.com/friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui) plugin to help you easily use Bootstrap with CakePHP 3

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the markup of ellipsis *with templates*, so it is compatible with bootstrap

```
$this->Paginator->templates([
    'ellipsis' => '<li class="ellipsis"><span>...</span></li>',
    // Default looks like this
    //'ellipsis' => '<li class="ellipsis">...</li>',
]);
```

then use this to generate pagination links

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?= $this->Paginator->first(__('First'));?>
    <?= $this->Paginator->numbers([
        'modulus' => 2,
        'first' => 2,
        'last' => 2
    ]);?>
    <?= $this->Paginator->last(__('Last'));?>
</ul>
```

Code above changed the template dynamically, but you can also define and load your own reusable templates: [PaginatorHelper Templates](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#paginatorhelper-templates)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator'=>'','currentTag'=>'a', 'currentClass'=>'active','tag'=>'li','first'=>1,'ellipsis'=>'<li class="ellipsis"><span>...</span></li>')); ?>
```

Comment: I implemented it on CakePHP 2.x